# PHP - Creating time duration

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a duration time.

I have a user option to enter a time duration in any of these formats: 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 ect.

I have a WordPress post date (used as a start time) and the finish time is calculated with the above user inputs. Together they build a duration time.

**Example:**

A user enters 1 - Example Out: Duration: 16:30 - 17:30

**Problem:**

This currently cannot output the correct end time if a user enters anything other then a whole number.

So, 1,2,3 ect would work fine, but 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 will all error and show the wrong end time.

I am need of a second pair of eyes, I cannot see the error of my ways.

```
    // Get user duration option - 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2 ect
    $course_hours = floatval(get_field('hours'));
    $course_minutes = ($course_hours % 1) * 60;

    $end_hour = intval(get_the_date('H'));
    $end_minute = intval(get_the_date('i'));
    $end_ampm = get_the_date('a');

    if($course_minutes != 0 && $course_minutes + $end_minute <= 59){
        $end_minute += $course_minutes;
        $end_hour += floor($course_hours);
    }
    elseif($course_minutes != 0 && $course_minutes + $end_minute > 59){
        $end_minute = ($course_minutes + $end_minute) % 60;
        $end_hour += floor($course_hours) + 1;
    }
    elseif($course_minutes == 0){
        $end_hour += floor($course_hours);
        if ($end_minute == 0){$end_minute = '00';}
    }

    $end_time = $end_hour.':'.$end_minute;
    $safe_post_status = get_post_status();

    //Demo output
    echo the_date('d F Y G:i'); 
    echo ' - '.$end_time;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Writing logic for your question. Change the date format as per your requirement.
seems like you are using wordpress.

```
    $course_hours = (get_field('hours'));
    $course_minutes = ($course_hours) * 60;
    $formatter = [];
    $increment = 0.5;
    $h = $increment * 60;
    while ($h < $course_minutes ) {

        $key = date('H:i', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' + ' . $h . ' minutes'));
        $value = date('h:i', strtotime(date('Y-m-d') . ' + ' . $h . ' minutes'));
        $formatter[$key] = $value;
        $h = $h + ($increment * 60 );
    }
    echo $output = implode(" - ",$formatter);
    // 12:30 - 01:00 - 01:30 - 02:00
```

Comment: The output should be like: 16:00 - 16:30 or 09:00 - 10:00 ect. Could you update to reflect?

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood. Let me think over it

Comment: I do not 100% understand the edit, could you post within the context of my initial code?

Comment: You may need to do some changes for your requirement. execute this code and try to change a bit

Comment: Thanks for the input, what you have provided outputs increments of times. Not a time format like 12:30 - 13:00, which is what I am looking to make.

Comment: If its what you are looking for then please mark as correct ans :)

Comment: This does not work, I think it is more simple then you think. The start time is the post publish time. The end time is the user option, 0.5 or 1 ect. The output is just Publish time - User option. Ex: 15:00 - 15:30. Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it.